# How to deal with React's: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, axios

I have a component that has 3 charts(graphs), using React.js as a framework, `Highcharts` and `HighchartsReact` to create the charts.
To populate data to these charts, I make 3 requests to the server, to provide data for each chart.
When the component mounts, it makes the requests(using Axios), awaits for the response, passes the data to the chart, and then displays/draws in the DOM.

The way the app is structured:
Axios files:

- utils(get, post, put calls)
- interceptors

Components:

- App.jsx

  - Root.jsx

    - Charts.jsx
    - Other pages.jsx

Root.jsx:
its in this component that the chart component and other pages will display).
It has a navbar that, for example, when you click in the charts icon in the navbar, it will redirect to the chart page.
The navbar is always there.
Using react-router-dom to deal with the re-directions.

The problem:
While the requests are being made, if I access another page(same app), and the component unmounts, I get the error:
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

How do I deal with this?
Should I:

- Stop the requests on url change?
- Stop requests when the component unmounts?
- Other solutions??

I tried abortController but couldn't make it work.
Honestly, I don't even know if it makes sense to use it in my case.

```js
// axios utils
export const apiGetCall = (url) => axiosInstance.get(url);

// One of the function to get data from server and pass to chart

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await apiGetCall("/departments");
      const departmentsData = response.data.departments;

      // Update the state with the fetched department data
      setDepartmentData(departmentsData);

      // Move the contents of pieChartOptions to the useState hook
      setPieChartOptions({
        // Department data
      });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
  };

  fetchDepartmentData();
}, []);
```

I just inserted the relevant code. The chart display etc. is working fine.
I just need help dealing with the error.

Comment: Please share the axios code you are using. There you should use a cancel/abort token to cancel any inflight requests when the component unmounts.

Comment: The problem has been solved, but thank you for taking the time.
Regarding the axios code, I deleted it because it was not working.
But if you would be so kind, for knowledge purposes, please share your solution on cancelling the inflight requests.

Comment: The api getCall is what is already written in the code above.

Comment: Oh wow, totally missed that, apologies. I have provided an answer with example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I deal with this? Should I:
>
> - Stop the requests on url change?
> - Stop requests when component unmounts?
> - Other solutions??

Another option is to upgrade to version 18 of react, which removed this warning. It was removed, in part, because it can be misleading: your code doesn't actually mave a memory leak. You fetch data once, set state, then return. At that point, javascript can clean up closure variables. A persistent subscription could result in a memory leak (eg, a websocket that you forget to teardown), but you aren't doing that.

If you'd like to get rid of the warning without changing react versions, then you should add a cleanup function to your effect. You'll save a variable indicating it has unmounted, and then skip setting state if that variable has been set.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let cancelled = false;
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await apiGetCall("/departments");
      if (cancelled) {
        return;
      }
      const departmentsData = response.data.departments;

      // Update the state with the fetched departmentData
      setDepartmentData(departmentsData);

      // Move the contents of pieChartOptions to the useState hook
      setPieChartOptions({
        // Department data
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  fetchData();

  return () => {
    cancelled = true;
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time!!
I cannot change reacts version, so I went with the other proposed solution, the cleanup function, which got rid of the error.
It is good to know tho that in react 18 they removed it. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 2):

This warning is indicating that some asynchronous code/callback is still running even after the component that initiated the call has since unmounted. When a component unmounts you should cleanup these "connections" so there are no resource leaks.

In the past an "isMounted" check was established as a way to check if the component was still mounted and conditionally ***not*** attempt state updates, but this has since fallen out of recommendation and is considered a React anti-pattern.

Here you should use an abort token to cancel any inflight network requests when the component unmounts. (*Pattern is very similar to the older "isMounted" logic*).

See the [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) and Axios [Cancellation](https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation) docs for details.

Example implementation:

```js
// axios utils
// (0) Update apiGetCall function to consume an options object arg
export const apiGetCall = (url, options) => axiosInstance.get(url, options);
```

```js
// One of the function to get data from server and pass to chart
useEffect(() => {
  // (1) Create an abort controller
  const controller = new AbortController();

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await apiGetCall(
        "/departments",
        {
          // (2) Pass controller signal in options to GET call
          signal: controller.signal
        }
      );

      const departmentsData = data.departments;

      // Update the state with the fetched department data
      setDepartmentData(departmentsData);

      // Move the contents of pieChartOptions to the useState hook
      setPieChartOptions({
        // Department data
      });
    } catch (err) {
      // (4) Aborted request Promise rejection, cancel error
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  fetchData();

  return () => {
    // (3) Abort in-flight request on component unmount
    controller.abort();
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you Drew.
I will try to implement.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but somehow i get the error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status'). trying to work on it tho.

Comment: @raio Where are you trying to read any `status` property? I had created a codesandbox to test/verify that Axios returns a Promise rejection with an error object, but it was a minimal mocking.